# how can I change the data inside the Map via Input?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, express

i have some array

```
    let questions = [
    {
        questionText: 'Write something',
        answerOptions: [
            { answerText: 'Here', isCorrect: false },
            { answerText: 'and here', isCorrect: false },
            { answerText: 'and here also', isCorrect: false },
            { answerText: 'and here also also', isCorrect: false },
        ],
    },           {
        questionText: 'Write something',
        answerOptions: [
            { answerText: 'Here', isCorrect: false },
            { answerText: 'and here', isCorrect: false },
            { answerText: 'and here also', isCorrect: false },
            { answerText: 'and here also also', isCorrect: false },
        ],
    },           {
        questionText: 'Write something',
        answerOptions: [
            { answerText: 'Here', isCorrect: false },
            { answerText: 'and here', isCorrect: false },
            { answerText: 'and here also', isCorrect: false },
            { answerText: 'and here also also', isCorrect: false },
        ],
    },
];
```

const [currentQuestion, setCurrentQuestion] = useState(0);

And I would like to do something similar

```
questions[0].questionText = 'How much is 2+2??'
questions[0].answerOptions[0].answerText = '4'
questions[0].answerOptions[0].answerText = '2'
questions[0].answerOptions[0].answerText = '1'
questions[0].answerOptions[0].answerText = '0'
```

and I would like to change this via "input", or rather first set it on the site, and then write it in " questions "after clicking on the" next " button, for example. I tried to do this via onChange, but nothing worked

```
    const handleAnswerChange = (value, index) => {
    const questionsCopy = [...questions] //Make a copy to avoid mutating state directly
    questionsCopy[currentQuestion].answerOptions[index].answerText = value
    questions = questionsCopy
    setCurrentQuestion(questions)
}
const handleQChange = (value) => {
    const questionsCopy = [...questions] //Make a copy to avoid mutating state directly
    questionsCopy[currentQuestion].questionText = value
    questions = questionsCopy
    setCurrentQuestion(questions)
}
```

and in return

```
 <>
                <div className='question-section'>
                    <div className='question-count'>
                        <span>Question {currentQuestion}</span>/{questions.length}
                    </div>
                    <div className='question-text'>

                        <input value={questions[currentQuestion].questionText}
                               onChange={event => handleQChange(event.target.value)} />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className='answer-section'>
                    {questions[currentQuestion].answerOptions.map((answerOption, index) => (
                        <input value={answerOption.answerText}
                               onChange={event => handleAnswerChange(event.target.value, index)} />
                    ))}
                </div>
            </>
```

[Here is the full code](https://github.com/adelliceee/mylms/blob/master/client/src/pages/QuizGameCreator.js)

Comment: @Nur i updated the link

Comment: I tried your link, It just print "Hi! Click me" , Make sure, what you want show us, So that we could see what's wrong in your code..

Comment: you don't need to  create `questionsCopy ` from `questions ` , modify it, and then replace again to `questions` , its unnecessary, In my knowledge, only `currentQuestion` is immutable

Comment: Other things look good to me though. In this context , The actual problem isn't clear to me, Need more info,

Comment: `// "Make a copy to avoid mutating state directly"`,  You super-duper do modify state directly, Because  only `questionsCopy`(array) is cloned but its value isn't , Because  its value is not primitive type, its an object, So by modifying it, will modify original  source (`questions`)

Comment: @Nur how do I fix this?

Comment: The actual problem is not there, that what you mention  in your question (code), But I think the issue was somewhere else, So Need more info...

Comment: @Nur https://github.com/adelliceee/mylms here is the whole code please help me understand, specifically, this page is here https://github.com/adelliceee/mylms/blob/master/client/src/pages/QuizGameCreator.js

Comment: Just cloned your git repo, Now How could I reproduce  issue ?

Comment: 1. npm install
2. npm run dev 3.http://localhost:3000/quizcreator

Comment: Isn't it on port 5000?

Comment: client on port 3000, server - 5000

Comment: All right, Create an issue on your [repo](https://github.com/adelliceee/mylms), I will look at it later...